# googleplus Counts the Same Over Multiple Pages with different parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, count

I am also facing the same issue 
iam using  the url /+1/fastbutton?url=myurl&count=true">https://plusone.google.com/u/0//+1/fastbutton?url=myurl&count=true to get the count
http://website.com/abc/test1.aspx?Episode=Episode-1&Cat=Cat1 count 10

when iam sharing this url google plus is taking only 
url http://website.com/abc/test1.aspx?Episode=Episode-1 it's neglecting Cat parameter 
based on the above url it is giving same count . how to handle url in parameters for google plus